# How to make the output recognizable in Sweave

Tags: r, knitr, sweave

I am using Sweave to be able to combine LaTeX and R. I find useful to be able to remove the prefix ">" and "+" from the input writing `options(prompt=" ", continue=" ")` .

I would like to find a way to make the output recognizable from the input, for instance adding a prefix "#" to the output (as it happens with R Markdown).

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you know that **knitr** can also compile `.Rnw` documents (Sweave), in addition to `.Rmd` (R Markdown). You just pass the file path to `knitr::knit()`, e.g.,

```r
knitr::knit('test.Rnw')
```

And you will get the `.tex` output file. If you want to get the PDF output directly, you may call:

```r
knitr::knit2pdf('test.Rnw')
```

By default, **knitr** doesn't add the prompt character `>` or `+` to your code in the output.

Comment: I was compiling using directly the button in RStudio. I tried what you suggested but I get the error message "Error in eval(x, envir = envir) : object 'tex' not found. It seems you are using the Sweave-specific syntax in line(s) 57, 74, 95, 111, 116; you may need Sweave2knitr("esercizi_stat_descr.Rnw") to convert it to knitr"

Comment: The error message has told you what to do. Did you try that?

Comment: I realize now that it creates another Rnw file which can be compiled with knitr. The only difference with the previous one seems to be an R chunck with `library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(concordance=TRUE)` replacing `\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}`. Looking at some examples it seems that such R chunck can be removed. I understand that I can get used to compile .Rnw files with knitr rather than Sweave just omitting '\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}'. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you can remove the `concordance` setting (chunk).

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot! I believe that knitr offers the best output when combining LaTeX and R.